# SQLAlchemy: Trouble querying in manyto many relationship

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

New to SQLalchemy, an sql queries in general but hopefully this will be clear to someone :)  In a Flask application,  I have two models, User and classes, in a many to many relationship

Here is the models.py

```
user_to_classes = db.Table('user_to_classes', Base.metadata,
db.Column('class_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('classes.id')),
db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
)



class Classes(db.Model):
    __tablename__= 'classes'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    participants = db.relationship('User', secondary=user_to_classes, backref = db.backref('classes',lazy='dynamic'))
    classtype_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('classtype.id'))
    status = db.Column(db.Integer)  #1 = open, 0 = closed

class User(UserMixin,db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64),unique=True,index=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(64))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(64))
    fullname = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    telephone = db.Column(db.String(64))
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    member_since = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
    notes = db.Column(db.Text())
    punchcard_passes = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

I am trying to know how many classes attended a user.  I have no problem querying how many users participated in a class, but not the reverse as there is no value to query in the user model.  Is it even possible?  Not being fluent in SQL queries, I am not sure what to search for either on google.  All the exemples I have seen do a one way query, and never the other way.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about `len(user.classes)` ? Doesn't it work ?

In addition: don't name a class in plural, since an object of it represents only one class.

Comment: No, it says 
    TypeError: object of type 'AppenderBaseQuery' has no len()

And yeah, I made alot of rookie mistakes in my variable names so far.  But I'm afraid to refractor because it would probably break a tons of calls.

Comment: I am an idiot.  It never occured to me that I only needed to declare the relationship in the User model too.  I've added the db.relationship('Classes',secondary=user_to_classes,backref = db.backref('users',lazy='dynamic')) to it and I can now indeed do a simple len(user.classes).  Thanks for putting me on the right track!

Comment: Actually, you don't need. That's what backref for, read the docs here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/backref.html

So, you need to declare many-to-many in only one of them.

Comment: Strange then, user.classes wouldn't work until I added a declaration in user too.  I'll remove it and go read that doc to try to get a hang of it and make it work.  Thanks